# iOS UITableViewCell subclass with multiple UITextFields scrolls out of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

**Some background:**
I am using a `UITableViewController` subclass for a long list of different types of cells. So technically, this is not an appropriate use of the `UITableViewController`, or `UITableView` in general. However, I'm working with a LARGE legacy code base - refactoring this is not an option.

One of the cells, let's call `ProductListCell` is composed of multiple views (which really should each be a cell, but again LARGE legacy code base), that are put together programatically.

The view, lets call `ProductListView` is drawn on a nib but slapped together programmatically with constraints in the `ProductListCell`, when data for the cell is provided in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Each of these `ProductListView`s have a `UITextField`. So there are multiple `UITextFields` in this `ProductListCell`.

**The problem:**
Sometimes, not always, when the textfield is tapped and the keyboard appears, the textfield is pushed up out of view.

I've tried passing out the textfield from the `ProductListView`, through the superview cell, to the `UITableViewController` subclass, and observing keyboard appearing, then `scrollToRectVisible:` to the textfield. I've done it with and without the `[self.tableView convertPoint:fromView:];`.

I do think that because the heights for multiple cells in this `UITableViewController` are not defined, but dynamic based on the data fed to them, it messes with the default keyboard appearance scroll behavior.

Anyone run into similar issues?

EDIT: I should have mentioned - my guess is that the `UITableViewController` knows how to show a textfield in a cell. But when there are **multiple** textfields in a cell, I believe it just focuses on the cell, not particularly the textfield.

Comment: Do you use self-sizing cells? TVC should scroll to reveal selected text field

Comment: @Andy Yes, when there is a textfield in it's cell, the TVC should know to go to the cell with the textfield. But what about when there are multiple **textfields** in the cell? I don't think the TVC knows which textfield to go to. Just the cell in general.

Answer (score 0):

dynamic content should not be
problem. as keyboard it's height is fixed. You just have to scoll that area where keyboard is now displayed. Register for keyboardNotifications and try this it might help.

```
CGSize kbSize = [[[sender userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
NSTimeInterval duration = [[[sender userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

CGFloat height = UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]) ? kbSize.width : kbSize.height;

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = _generalTableView.contentInset;
edgeInsets.bottom += height;
_generalTableView.contentInset = edgeInsets;
edgeInsets = _generalTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets;
edgeInsets.bottom += height;
_generalTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = edgeInsets;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code keep your textfield at the top of the view.
You can add this code in `UITextField`'s one of the delegate method `textFieldDidBeginEditing`

```
CGRect frame = CGRectZero;
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.origin.y = textField.tag*ROW_HEIGHT+textField.frame.origin.y+textField.frame.size.height*2+5;
frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
frame.size.height = RESULTS_TABLE_HEIGHT;
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, frame.origin.y-30)animated:YES];
```

// 30 : textfield height in tableview cell